# Mockito stubbing returning null when any Any arguments are used for method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, stubbing

I have the below method which I want to sub:

```
ProductArray productsArray;
productsArray = dataService.getProducts(ProductFilter pf, Date date1, Date date2, boolean matured);
```

In my test class I have below

```
ProductArray productsArrayTest = getProductsArrayForTest();
Mockito.when(dataServiceMock.getProducts(Mockito.any(ProductFilter.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Boolean.class))).thenReturn(productsArrayTest);
```

However in this test `productsArray` returns as `null`;

Mockito gives the below warning

```
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at 
com.company.util.TestProduct.testProductLoad(TestProduct.java:157)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at 
com.company.datastore.ProductLoader.processAll(ProductLoaderProcess.java:158)
```

What could be the reason for this?

Edit:

```
private ProductArray getProductsArrayTest() {
    ProductArray pa = new ProductArray();
    Product product = createProduct();
    pa.add(product);
    return pa;
}

private Product createProduct() {
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setPrice(1.23);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: "DataService.getProducts" is this a static method?

Comment: no it is not a static method

Comment: Could you post the code of getProductsArrayForTest() method? And DataService is a class but the call DataService.getProducts() is not static?

Comment: there was a mistake in my post, should have been a lower case d for DataService, have posted the code.

Comment: Does it help when you write it like this:

doReturn(productsArrayTest).when(dataServiceMock).getProducts(Mockito.any(ProductFilter.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Boolean.class));

Answer (score 1):

- Edit after the first comment -
  I see that you call the method getProductsArrayForTest() while you define getProductsArrayTest(). Check if it is only a mistake in the post or even in the code.
  However here is the code and the test succeeds.

  ```
  public class Product {
   double price;
   public Product() {

   }
   public double getPrice() {
    return this.price;
   }
   public void setPrice(double value) {
    this.price=value;
   }
  }
  ```

  ProductArray.class

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;


  public class ProductArray {
   private List<Product> productList;
   public ProductArray() {
    productList=new ArrayList<Product>();

   }
   public void add(Product product) {
    this.productList.add(product);
   }
   public List<Product> getProductList(){
    return this.productList;
   }
  }
  ```

  ProductTest.class

  ```
  public class ProductTest {
   @Test
   public void testProduct() {
    DataService dataserviceMock = Mockito.mock(DataService.class);
    ProductArray productsArrayTest = getProductsArrayTest();
    Mockito.when(dataserviceMock.getProducts(Mockito.any(ProductFilter.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(productsArrayTest);
    assertEquals(1, dataserviceMock.getProducts(null , null , null , false).getProductList().size());
   }
   private ProductArray getProductsArrayTest() {
       ProductArray pa = new ProductArray();
       Product product = createProduct();
       pa.add(product);
       return pa;
   }

   private Product createProduct() {
       Product p = new Product();
       p.setPrice(1.23);
       return p;
   }

  }
  ```

Comment: i 'm going to change the answer so i can show you my code

Comment: Did you solve it? Do you have any news? @user3809938

Comment: not with mockito, i had to use jmock "any" functionality which worked.